# Do you know about wordpress “pingatorpin”?

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently i saw a folder named "pingatorpin" in my wordpress plugin directory. Anybody know about this? I didn't installed it in my wordpress site. Is my site hacked?

The site was too slow last few days and now its working perfectly after removing "pingatorpin" from plugins. But I don't know how this plugin came in my wordpress.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress - especially pre-installed versions on low end hosting - are low hanging fruit for anyone looking to pwn a site.

The current version of the core software is relatively secure and bug free- but the quality of plugins, and historical versions of Wordpress vary greatly.

I've recently seen a dozen or so instances where a pronouncable but random directory name has been created in the plugins directory and used to host phishing sites. Did you by any chance keep the content? If it is a phishing site then I'm sure the entity being impersonated would be interested in the code and traffic logs.

Beyond that....you have fixed the symptoms, but you now know that your site is vulnerable. There is only one course of action:

Nuke from high orbit

Rebuild the software stack using the latests production versions of the software

Restore data from backup

(and if you manage the server then get some intrusion detection software installed)

Answer (score 1):

It's a fake plugin (malware) that adds a file to your body class and then floods your site with spam. More info on [this Sucuri.net article](http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/11/another-fake-wordpress-plugin-and-yet-another-spam-infection.html) of November 22, 2013